# Mock a model using rspec 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

I have a below `model` class. How can i `mock` this class and methods so that i don't hit the API.

```
class User
  get :all, '/user'
  get :find, '/user/:id'
end
```

Below is my `spec` where i would like to test the all and find method without hitting the API.

```
RSpec.describe User do
  it 'finds an user' do
    //User.find(id: '22', authorization: @auth);
  end
end
```

How can i mock the model and its method so that i can test it without hitting the API.

Comment: What's the functionality that you want to test?

Comment: Also there's presumably something more in your model that you aren't showing or just loading that class would raise a nomethoderror

Comment: Mathew: Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stub an expected method call with expected parameters and returning a model mock like:

```
    User.should_receive(:find).with(search_parameters).and_return(mock_model(User))
```

but I guess you don't need to, since I assume find to be already tested.